# Using And But together in a sentence

Tags: sentence-construction, conjunctions

I have referred [this](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/134087/can-two-conj-but-and-because-be-used-together) question but I am not clear still.

Is this sentence grammatically correct, Can we use And But together for example

> The mausoleum will not only be the first remarkable example of Mughal
>   architecture in the country **and but** will also become a prime
>   archetype to upcoming projects of the dynasts, including the Taj
>   Mahal. ([source](https://www.google.com/amp/s/indianexpress.com/article/cities/delhi/bega-begum-the-mughal-empress-who-gave-delhi-humayuns-tomb-6304741/lite/))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No you can't.

You need to drop the **and**.

The sentence then contrasts the use of **not only** with the natural follow up **but..also**.

You will find numerous examples and explanations of the usage at sources such as these.

https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/not-only-but-also
https://www.grammarly.com/blog/parallelism-with-not-only-but-also/
https://www.dailywritingtips.com/5-tips-for-fixing-%E2%80%9Cnot-only-but-also%E2%80%9D-errors/